# Correct the algorithm of image filter code (TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to write an image filter. Here's the algorithm:

[image]

i is a row, j is a column, m(i,j) is a pixel, s(i,j) is a sum of pixels, max(m(i,j)) is a max pixel in a row, k is a coefficient (0.7), m is an array of RGB average.

Before using this algorithm I firstly need to convert the image to grayscale. Here a code in python:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_path = 'image.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(img_path)
imgshape = img.shape

fix_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

R, G, B = fix_img[:,:,0], fix_img[:,:,1], fix_img[:,:,2]

grayscale_img = np.mean(fix_img, axis=2)

s = np.array([0][0])
b = np.ones(imgshape[:2])
k = 0.7
rows, cols = imgshape[:2] #(192, 184, 3)

for j in grayscale_img(rows):
    for i in grayscale_img(cols):
        max = np.amax(grayscale_img, axis=1)[j]
        s[j,i] = s[j,i] + max
        if s[j,i] >= (k*max):
            s[j,i] = s[j,i] - (k*max)
            s[j,i] = s[j,i] + max
            b[j,i] = 1
        else: 
            s[j,i] = s[j,i] + max
            b[j,i] = 0

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I run this code I get an error:

> for j in grayscale_img(rows):
> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

What is the reason? Please help correct the code.

Here an example how the filter should filter an image:
[click on image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJivZ.png)

EDIT: I have corrected code, according to suggestions on comments:

```
...
s = np.array([0][0])
b = np.ones(imgshape[:2])
k = 0.7
rows, cols = imgshape[:2] #(192, 184, 3)

for j in range(grayscale_img.shape[1]):
    for i in range(grayscale_img.shape[0]):
        max = np.amax(grayscale_img, axis=1)[j]
        m = grayscale_img[j,i]
        s[j,i] = s[j,i] + m
        if s[j,i] >= (k*max):
            s[j,i] = s[j,i] - (k*max)
            s[j,i] = s[j,i] + m
            b[j,i] = 1
        else: 
            s[j,i] = s[j,i] + m
            b[j,i] = 0
```

But get the next error in line

```
s[j,i] = s[j,i] + m
```

> IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

How to correct it?

Comment: Please explain the algorithm further - it is not clear what s_{i,j} is the sum of, and it is not clear how m_{i,j} is a pixel but max(m_{i,j}) is the max pixel in a row? The notation is not clear... In any case, the way to fix that particular error you are getting is to do: `for i in range(grayscale_img.shape[0])` and `for j in range(grayscale_img.shape[1])`

Comment: this is not an OpenCV issue, it's a python/numpy issue -- that's not valid python expression for numpy arrays: `grayscale_img(rows)`. the error already tells you. you can't *call* a numpy array. that's what you're doing there, trying to call it. if you wanted to iterate over the row and column indices, you'll first need to know the width and height of the image, and then you can `for i in range(height):` -- further, indexing is [i,j] which is [y,x] so either stick with x and y or swap the i,j because those variables are mixed up. in a matrix, j is customarily the row index, not column index.

Comment: @elbashmubarmeg max(m_{i,j}) is max value of array of m_{i,j}. We compare this max with other values in a row. I changed the code according to your suggestions and get the next error: 
s[j,i] = s[j,i] + max 
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Comment: Post a reference to your image of the math for the algorithm that you want. It is not clear what you are doing there on the right side that is not part of the threshold operation.

Comment: @fmw42 Here a math form of algorithm: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn4U8.jpg . Here how a result should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJivZ.png . I did not build this algorithm, it's a task from my teacher

Comment: I do not understand all the math on the right side of the `=>`. Can you explain it?

Comment: @fmw42 if we get b(i,j)=1 it means that firstly we subtract k*max(m(i,j)) and then accumulation of the sum (s(i,j)) continues. if we get b(i,j)=0 we do only the second operation

Comment: I understood that part. But what is all the rest of the stuff to the right of that.

Comment: If you have to do all those extra things, then you have `s[j,i] = s[j,i] + max` but your algorithm does not say that `max` is the same as `m(i,j)`

Comment: @fmw42 my mistake. I have added m = grayscale_img[j,i] before if statement, and sum function is now: s[j,i] = s[j,i] + m. But I still get an error in this line: IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 2 were indexed. I edited this topic, so you can see an updated code

Comment: A particular pixel is image[y:y+1, x:x+1]. But it is much faster to process as Numpy arrays with Numpy functions and OpenCV functions to do your arithmetic than to use double indices.

Comment: You need to add your channel number to your array as a third index and loop over the channel as well. Or use Numpy image processing functions to avoid looping.

Comment: @fmw42 can you show me how to use numpy image processing functions here instead of using double indices?

Comment: Your equation comment is "i is a row, j is a column, m(i,j) is a pixel, s(i,j) is a sum of pixels, max(m(i,j)) is a max pixel in a row, k is a coefficient (0.7), m is an array of RGB average."  That is unclear!  What is s(i,j) a sum over? How can m be an array and also an average?  Why do you convert from BGR to RGB just to separate channels. Then you do not make use of them? And you then simply convert your image to grayscale as the average of the channels.

Comment: Your conditional is unclear. All the equations separated by "=>", are they to be processed before the test or after the test? Is this an iterative process or does the value of s for a given pixel inherit the value from the previous pixel in a row? Can you provide a reference to the concept that you are trying to implement?

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea what this algorithm is doing, but here is my interpretation in Python/OpenCV trying to correct your code.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('red_cell.png')
imgshape = img.shape
print(imgshape)

gray = np.mean(img, axis=2)
grayshape = gray.shape
print(grayshape)

s = np.zeros(grayshape[:2])
print(s.shape)
b = np.zeros(grayshape[:2])
print(b.shape)
k = 0.7

for j in range(grayshape[0]):
    max = np.amax(gray, axis=1)[j]
    km = k * max
    for i in range(grayshape[1]):
        m = gray[j,i]
        s[j,i] = s[j,i] + m
        if s[j,i] >= km:
            b[j,i] = 1
            s[j,i] = s[j,i] - km
            s[j,i] = s[j,i] + m
        else: 
           #b[j,i] = 0 (since b is already initialized to zero)
           s[j,i] = s[j,i] + m

cv2.imwrite('red_cell_thresh.png', (255*b).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imshow('b',b)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

It is not the same as what you show in your example. But it runs without error.

I leave it to you to correct it.

As it is, all the updates of s go unused. I suspect that the value of s is corrected before the next pixel and used to increment its value rather than resetting it to m.  So you may want to use s[j,i] = s[j,i-1] + m. But without a reference to what this should be doing, I can only guess.